# Menu Navigation Does not change in style using Jquery addClass()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar and I want this to be dynamically working. When I try to activate another menu in the navigation bar, the jquery code which changes the active menu works but its styling does not apply to the new selected menu. can someone please take a look at my code? Maybe I might miss something in my code or what.

```
                  <!--HTML-->
                 <div class = "side-nav-bar content">
                            <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
                            <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
                    </div>

                     <!--css-->
                    .side-nav-bar .active-menu {
                    background-color: #293c4e;
                     color: #ffffff;
                      }

                       .active {
                        background-color: #293c4e
                                color: #ffffff;
                       }

                     <!--jquery-->
                   $('.side-nav-bar a').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.side-nav-bar 
                                 a').not(this).removeClass('active');
        });

                 <!-- jquery is a code snippet only.-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery add and remove class work just fine. There was just a simple error in your css with no semi-colon between your two attributes in the active class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.side-nav-bar a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.side-nav-bar a ').not(this).removeClass('active ');
  });

});
```

```css
.side-nav-bar .active-menu {
  background-color: #293c4e;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  background-color: #293c4e;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-bar content">
  <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
  <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine here but mine doesn't. It still doesn't change the background color.

Comment: There must be code outside of what you've shown that's interfering with it. It's hard to say without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your one wrong one, background-color then use a semicolon , 
you will need to type this style code

```css
.active {
background-color: #293c4e;
color: #ffffff;
}
```